# How to get Data as Object from Firebase to Service and then to Page correctly (Angularfire + ionic4)?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4, angularfire

I am trying to get data from Firebase Realtimedatabase to my `mypage.page` via `firebase.service`:

- I can get simple data (strings for example) inside the `firebase.service` and `mypage.page`, but I can’t load objects into `mypage.page`.
- In console I get bunch of error messages `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`.

Console log:

```
core.js:6479 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at MypagePage_Template (template.html:8)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9598)
    at refreshView (core.js:9464)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10635)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9261)
    at refreshView (core.js:9514)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10589)
    at refreshView (core.js:9488)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10635)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9261)
```

### How can I pass `Object` through `Promise` from `firebase.service` to `mypage.page`?

---

### [Parent question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246370/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-to-service-and-then-to-page-correctly-angularfire/69246507#69246507)

`mypage.page.ts` code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataObject, FirebaseService } from '../firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mypage',
  templateUrl: './mypage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mypage.page.scss'],
})
export class MypagePage implements OnInit {
  localData: DataObject;

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
    this.firebaseService.getData().then(data => {
      this.localData = data;
   }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`firebase.service.ts` code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { DatabaseReference } from '@angular/fire/compat/database/interfaces';

export interface DataObject{
  id: string;
  data: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {
  databaseRef: DatabaseReference;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.databaseRef = db.database.ref(); //Create databaseReference
  }

  getData(): Promise<any> {
    return this.databaseRef.child('data').get().then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        return {id: '1', data: snapshot.val()};
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

`mypage.page.html` code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>mypage</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-label>{{ localData.id }}</ion-label>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as expected, the error that you get is because the `localData` is indeed `undefined` until the data comes from the network.

You have 2 solutions for this:

1. Either give `localData` an initial value, so it's no longer `undefined`:

```
export class MypagePage implements OnInit {
  localData: Partial<DataObject> = {};
  // ...
}
```

2. Put an `ngIf` on the label and just don't display it while the data is not there yet:

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-label *ngIf="localData">{{ localData.id }}</ion-label>
</ion-content>
```